# How can I use space according to variables value?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
mystring = "A:\"" + var1 + var2 + var3 + "\"";
```

var1 var2 and var3 sometimes get null, sometimes getting string. When variables getting string, mystring returning like this:

```
A:"var1valuevar2valuevar3value"
```

I need to show like this:

```
A:"var1value var2value var3value"
```

I tried like this:

```
mystring = "A:\"" + var1 + " " + var2 + " " + var3 + "\"";
```

It's working but when variables get null, its returning like this:

```
A:" var2value var3value"
```

How can I remove unnecessary spaces? If a variable gets null, I don't need to have spaces between two variables or first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
mystring = "A:\"" + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(var1) ? (var1 + " ") : "") + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(var2) ? (var2 + " ") : "") + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(var3) ? (var3 + " ") : "") + "\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ to filter out the empties, and use `string.Join` to concatenate them:

```
string s = string.Join( " "
                      , new string [] {var1, var2, var3}
                            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                      )
```

Comment: the only answer without redundancy and double spaces +1

Comment: You need to convert vars to strings (if they are **not** of `string` type): e.g. `var1.ToString()` inside array declaration. Or it will [not work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V9yyh6).

Comment: OP mentioned *var1 var2 and var3 sometimes getting `null`*, so they are either strings or some other reference types (and not value types as in my test), [shrug](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NWEogy). P.S.: I feel pedantic.

Comment: @Sinatr Okay. Just leave your comment as reference to OP. He might want to change it if it indeed aren't strings.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for null value is your string:

```
mystring = "A:\"" + GetString(var1) + GetString(var2) + GetString(var3, true) + "\"";

public string GetString(string str, bool isLast = false)
{
   if (isLast)
       return str;
   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "" : str + " ";
}
```

Comment: Will not work if `var3 = null`, logic to determine last item is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
string mystring = "A:\"" + AddSpace(var1) + AddSpace(var2) + var3 + "\"";

        public string AddSpace(String var)
        {
             return var == null ? "" : var + " ";
        }
```